# Create an array with first x happy numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to create an array that contains the first x happy numbers.

> A happy number can be defined as a number which will yield 1 when it is replaced by the sum of the square of its digits repeatedly. If this process results in an endless cycle of numbers containing 4, then the number is called an unhappy number.

I have managed to write two functions: one to sum the squared digits and one to check if a number is happy:

```
public static int sumDigitSquare(int n) {
    if(n < 10)
        return (int) (Math.pow(n,2));

    return (int) (Math.pow((n%10),2)) + sumDigitSquare(n/10);
}

public static boolean isHappy(int n) {
    int res = sumDigitSquare(n);

    while(res != 1 && res != 4) {
        res = sumDigitSquare(res);  
    }

    if(res == 1) 
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now I would like to add a function `public static int[] happyArray(int x)`
which returns the first x happy numbers as an array, but I am not sure how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. It does not, however, verify that your other methods are correct.

- allocate an array to store them
- the first number, `n`, is set to 1.
- keep interating until x numbers are found
- increment `n` for each iteration of the while loop.
- return the array when `x` numbers have been found.

```
public static int[] getHappy(int x) {
    int n = 1;
    int[] happyNumbers = new int[x];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < x) {
        if (isHappy(n)) {
            happyNumbers[i++] = n;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return happyNumbers;
}
```